# How to make a local form to stored in Django admin

Tags: python, django

i tried for make Django project and make a local form to stored in django admin  here is my "view.py" file code

```
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from templates.forms import Registrationform
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

def home(request):
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    name = 'max'
    
    args = {'myName': name,'numbers':numbers}
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html',args)

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account')
    else:
        form = Registrationform()
        
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)

def view_profile(request):
    args ={'user':request.user}
    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)  

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account/profile')
        
    else: 
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        args={'form':form}
        return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html')
```

**there is my another file that named forms.py and the errors came with **registrationform****

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import fields 


class Registrationform (UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'

        )
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(Registrationform, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

and another error is: module 'accounts.views' has no attribute 'profile' and sometimes can't import views also!!

Comment: is your template folder in same folder as ```view.py```?

Comment: yes I was paying attention to that

Comment: can you show your project structure? command like ```tree -d``` can help(based on your OS).

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Registrationform? You say it is living inside your 'templates' app/module, but Django can't find 'templates'. If it's inside the same directory as your views.py you can just import it with:

```
from .forms import Registrationform
```

Comment: Registrationform is in another folder form.py still it dosent work anymore

Comment: Have you stuck an empty _ _ init _ _.py in that folder?

Comment: yesss :))))))))